# Skip activity in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

How can we skip activities in android?

I have 4 activities and from **Activity A** I need to move to **Activity C**. Is it possible?

**First flow :** `Activity A` - `Activity B` - `Activity C` - `Activity D`

**Second Flow :** `Activity A` - `Activity B` - `Activity D` ***//skip Activity C***

Comment: Post the error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flow is like this :

**First flow :**   SomeActivity -> CreateCustomer -> ShopActivity -> AddressActivity

**Second flow :** AddCustomer -> CreateCustomer -> AddressActivity

Try with below code : only this for Second Flow , send `source` for skip Activity.

**AddCustomer** class :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_customer);

        //inside click listner
        Intent i = new Intent(AddCustomer.this,CreateCustomer.class);
                    i.putExtra("SOURCE", "ADD_CUSTOMER");
                    startActivity(i);

    }
```

**CreateCustomer** class : Here only you want ship ShopActivity

```
String source = "";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_customer);

         //if source will be AddCustomer it will skip ShopActivity
         if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
         {
           source = getIntent().getExtras().getString("SOURCE");
         }

         //inside click listner
         if(source.equals("ADD_CUSTOMER"))
         {
           Intent i = new Intent(CreateCustomer.this,AddressActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);

         }else{

           Intent i = new Intent(CreateCustomer.this,ShopActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to `startActivity()` with your conditions from which you decide which activity to open. Refer to pseudo code below:

```
          if(condition == "B"){
             Intent toActivityB = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class)
             startActivity(toActivityB)
          } else {
             Intent toActivityC = new Intent(this,ActivityC.class)
             startActivity(toActivityC)
          }
```

Comment: For that you'll have to maintain flag, you can use "putExtra" method of intent and pass and convey that through you series of activities, so when you trigger new activity from D you check that flag if the source from "A" or "B" and go to "E" or directly to "F" @RSM